# How can I generate trace file in IIS 7 for a website

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I just want a IIS trace file .. the sample has given below . Can any one please provide me the steps to generate the IIS trace file as given below.

--
Thanks in Advance .

//** sample **//

Request n.37: http://domain1.com:80/common/css/build/Styles.css
{00000000-0000-0000-b50f-0060400000f4} 2008-0-16 11:43:8

IISGeneral: GENERAL_REQUEST_START - IIS starts processing a new request
AppPoolId: DefaultAppPool
ConnId: 1073745844
RawConnId: 0
RequestURL: http://domain1.com:80/common/css/build/Styles.css
RequestVerb: GET
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISFilter: FILTER_START - W3 filter starts
FilterName: C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite\ISAPI_Rewrite.dll
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISFilter: FILTER_PREPROC_HEADERS_START - Filter starts PREPROC_HEADERS
notification
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISFilter: FILTER_SET_REQ_HEADER - IIS filter SET_REQ_HEADER
HeaderName: X-Rewrite-URL:
HeaderValue: /common/css/build/Styles.css
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISFilter: FILTER_SET_REQ_HEADER - IIS filter SET_REQ_HEADER
HeaderName: host:
HeaderValue: domain2.com
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISFilter: FILTER_SET_REQ_HEADER - IIS filter SET_REQ_HEADER
HeaderName: URL
HeaderValue: /common/css/build/Styles.css
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISFilter: FILTER_PREPROC_HEADERS_END - Filter ends PREPROC_HEADERS
notification
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISFilter: FILTER_END - W3 filter ends
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISFilter: FILTER_START - W3 filter starts
FilterName:
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_filter.dll
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISFilter: FILTER_PREPROC_HEADERS_START - Filter starts PREPROC_HEADERS
notification
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISFilter: FILTER_SET_REQ_HEADER - IIS filter SET_REQ_HEADER
HeaderName: AspFilterSessionId:
HeaderValue:
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISFilter: FILTER_PREPROC_HEADERS_END - Filter ends PREPROC_HEADERS
notification
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISFilter: FILTER_END - W3 filter ends
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISCache: URL_CACHE_ACCESS_START - IIS starts accessing URL cache to get
metadata
RequestURL: /common/css/build/Styles.css
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISGeneral: GENERAL_GET_URL_METADATA - IIS gets URL metadata
PhysicalPath: C:\domain2\domain2.com\common\css\build\Styles.css
AccessPerms: Read+Script
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISCache: URL_CACHE_ACCESS_END - IIS ends accessing URL cache
PhysicalPath: C:\domain2\domain2.com\common\css\build\Styles.css
ErrorCode: 0x00000000
URLInfoFromCache: 0
URLInfoAddedToCache: 0
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISFilter: FILTER_START - W3 filter starts
FilterName:
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_filter.dll
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

IISFilter: FILTER_URL_MAP_START - IIS starts URL_MAP notification
AccessPerms: 0x00000201
MatchingPath: 18
MatchingURL: 0
ScriptMapEntry:
OrigURL: /common/css/build/Styles.css
OrigPath: C:\domain2\domain2.com\common\css\build\Styles.css
ContextIDSeq: 37
Timestamp: 11:43:08.655.398400

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for Failed Request Tracing.

First, make sure it is installed. On client OSs, it can be found in "Turn Windows Features On and Off" :: Internet Information Services :: World Wide Web Services :: Health and Diagnostics :: Tracing

Next enable it for your website. Close/reopen the IIS Management Console if necessary, then select the website and select "Configure :: Failed Request Tracing..." in the right panel. Check "Enabled" and make note of the log folder.

Still in the website, select "Failed Request Tracing Rules". Click "Add" and go through the wizard to set your filter.

Browse the website and then look at the XML files in the log folder. They come with a stylesheet which allows the data to be navigated.

See also: [Troubleshooting Failed Requests Using Tracing in IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)

Comment: Hi,

Sorry, I still not able to see the IISFilter: FILTER_START - in my logs.